# Writing to shared memory in Python is very slow

Tags: python, linux, performance, numpy, shared-memory

I use `python.multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` to share large numpy arrays between multiple processes.  And I've noticed that when this array is large (> 1 or 2 Gb) it becomes very slow to initialize and also much slower to read/write to (and read/write time is not predictable, sometimes pretty fast, sometimes very very slow).

I've made a small sample script that uses just one process, initialize a shared array and write to it several times.  And measures time to do these operations.

```
import argparse
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes as mpsc
import numpy as np
import time

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--block-count', type=int, default=1,
                        help='Number of blocks to write')
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--block-width', type=int, default=20000,
                        help='Block width')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--block-depth', type=int, default=15000,
                        help='Block depth')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    blocks = args.block_count
    blockwidth = args.block_width
    depth = args.block_depth
    start = time.perf_counter()
    shared_array = mpsc.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint16, blocks*blockwidth*depth)
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print('Init shared array of size {:.2f} Gb: {:.2f} s'.format(blocks*blockwidth*depth*ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_uint16)/1024/1024/1024, (finish-start)))
    numpy_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array).reshape(blocks*blockwidth, depth)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(blocks):
        begin = time.perf_counter()
        numpy_array[i*blockwidth:(i+1)*blockwidth, :] = np.ones((blockwidth, depth), dtype=np.uint16)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print('Write = %.2f s' % (end-begin))
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print('Total time = %.2f s' % (finish-start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this code I get the following on my PC:

```
$ python shared-minimal.py -c 1
Init shared array of size 0.56 Gb: 0.36 s
Write = 0.13 s
Total time = 0.13 s
$ python shared-minimal.py -c 2
Init shared array of size 1.12 Gb: 0.72 s
Write = 0.12 s
Write = 0.13 s
Total time = 0.25 s
$ python shared-minimal.py -c 4
Init shared array of size 2.24 Gb: 5.40 s
Write = 1.17 s
Write = 1.17 s
Write = 1.17 s
Write = 1.57 s
Total time = 5.08 s
```

In the last case, when array size is more than 2 Gb, initialization time is not linearly dependent on array size, and assigning save size slices to the array is more than 5 times slower.

I wonder why that happens.  I'm running the script on Ubuntu 16.04 using Python 3.5.  I also noticed by using **iotop** that when initializing and writing to the array there is a disk writing activity with same size as shared array, but I'm not sure if a real file is created or it's only in-memory operation (I suppose it should be).  In general my system becomes less responsive as well in case of large shared array.  There is no swapping, checked with `top`, `ipcs -mu` and `vmstat`.

Comment: Does your system have 2gb of physical memory available? It sounds like it's swapping.

Comment: @pvg it has 16 gb of memory, and I've tested also on a computer with 64 gb of memory.  The results are not always the same, but on the computer with 16 gb of physical memory it starts to slowdown significantly when shared array is more than ~1.5 gb, and on the machine with 64 gb shared array is more then ~6.5 gb.  Also, I've tried running `top` and `ipcs -mu` and they don't show change in swap usage.

Comment: You probably want something like `vmstat` or anything else that lets you track actual swap ins and outs rather than usage. Memory access times can change non-linearly for various reasons but it's hard to explain disk access and non-responsive system by something other than swapping.

Comment: `vmstat` shows zero swap ins and swap outs as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more research I've found that python actually creates folders in `/tmp` which are starting with `pymp-`, and though no files are visible within them using file viewers, it looks exatly like `/tmp/` is used by python for shared memory.  Performance seems to be decreasing when file cashes are flushed.

The working solution in the end was to mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs`:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
```

And, if using the latest docker, by providing `--tmpfs /tmp` argument to the `docker run` command.

After doing this, read/write operations are done in RAM, and performance is fast and stable.

I still wonder why `/tmp` is used for shared memory, not `/dev/shm` which is already monted as `tmpfs` and is supposed to be used for shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `np.frombuffer`, which is much faster in my test.

just replace the following line

`numpy_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array).reshape(blocks*blockwidth, depth)`

with

`numpy_array = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=np.uint16).reshape(blocks*blockwidth, depth)`

Answer (score 2):

Since python 3.8 you can use [shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), which seems to be much more efficient and plays nicely with `numpy` arrays. I did some rough testing and creating an array with shape `(5000,5000)` took cca 3s with `multiprocessing.Array` and only cca 0.015s with `shared_memory.SharedMemory`

Below is a use case for `SharedMemory` where I create, with multiple processes, an array for each item that comes into the input queue and read them from a separate process in the same order as they come in.

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory    


class FunctionTimer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.exec_time = self.end - self.start
        print(f"{self.name} time: {self.exec_time}")


class MpArrayProcessor:
    def __init__(self, in_queue, out_queue):
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue
        self.stop_event = mp.Event()
        self.processes = []
        self.cur_id = 0
        self.order_dict = {}

        self.writable_dict = {}
        self.array_locks = {}
        self.array_data_dict = {}

    @staticmethod
    def wrap_func(func, arr_shape, in_queue, out_queue, stop_event, writable, shmem_name):
        pid = os.getpid()

        while True:
            if stop_event.is_set():
                print("Stopping")
                break
            x = in_queue.get(block=True)

            if x is None:
                break
            else:
                res = func(arr_shape, x)
                with FunctionTimer("Wait and write"):
                    writable.wait()
                    shmem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shmem_name, create=False)
                    c = np.ndarray(arr_shape, dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shmem.buf)
                    c[:] = res

                writable.clear()
                out_queue.put((pid, shmem_name, x))

    def start(self, func, arr_shape, n_proc):
        # TODO implement proper closing of SharedMemory
        for p in range(n_proc):
            writable = mp.Event()
            writable.set()

            shmem_name = f"ps_{p}"
            data = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr_shape[0] * arr_shape[1], name=shmem_name)
            p = mp.Process(target=self.wrap_func,
                           args=(
                               func, arr_shape, self.in_queue, self.out_queue, self.stop_event, writable, shmem_name))

            p.start()
            self.writable_dict[p.pid] = writable
            self.array_data_dict[p.pid] = data
            self.processes.append(p)

    def get(self):
        while True:
            if self.cur_id in self.order_dict:
                pid, shmem_name, order = self.order_dict[self.cur_id]
                print(f"PID: {pid}, idx: {order}, dict_len: {len(self.order_dict)}")
                shmem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shmem_name, create=False)
                result = np.copy(np.frombuffer(shmem.buf, dtype=np.uint8))
                self.writable_dict[pid].set()
                del self.order_dict[self.cur_id]
                self.cur_id += 1
                return result
            print(self.order_dict)
            pid, shmem_name, order = self.out_queue.get(block=True)
            if order == self.cur_id:
                print(f"PID: {pid}, idx: {order}, dict_len: {len(self.order_dict)}")
                shmem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shmem_name, create=False)
                print(np.frombuffer(shmem.buf, dtype=np.uint8))
                result = np.copy(np.frombuffer(shmem.buf, dtype=np.uint8))
                self.writable_dict[pid].set()

                self.cur_id += 1
                return result
            else:
                self.order_dict[order] = (pid, shmem_name, order)

    def close(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        print("Event set")
        for p in self.processes:
            self.array_data_dict[p.pid].close()
            self.array_data_dict[p.pid].unlink()
            p.join()
            print("Joined")
            p.close()
            print("Closed")



def create_data(shape, x):
    time.sleep(0.08)
    # np.random.randint(0, 255, shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    return np.ones(shape, dtype=np.uint8) * x


def fill_queue(queue, n_elements, n_processes):
    l = [x for x in range(n_elements)]
    for i in l:
        queue.put(i)
    for i in range(n_processes):
        queue.put(None)

    print("filling finished")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Running: {__file__}")
    print(f"Script dir: {os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}")
    print(f"Working dir: {os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())}")

    n = 100
    n_proc = 4
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    output_queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=50)
    # shape = (3, 3)
    # shape = (1280, 720)
    shape = (5000, 5000)


    in_proc = mp.Process(target=fill_queue, args=(input_queue, n, n_proc))
    in_proc.start()

    with FunctionTimer("MP processing"):
        arr_processor = MpArrayProcessor(input_queue, output_queue)
        arr_processor.start(create_data, shape, 4)

        results = []

        for i in range(n):
            print(f"Getting: {i}")
            r = arr_processor.get()[:shape[0]*shape[1]].reshape(shape)
            results.append(r)

        arr_processor.close()

    in_proc.join()
    in_proc.close()

    print(results)

    with FunctionTimer("Normal"):
        for i in range(n):
            a = create_data(shape, i)
```