# How to mount /tmp as tmpfs in singularity container

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, singularity-container

I am debugging some performance issues related to python multiprocessing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747145/writing-to-shared-memory-in-python-is-very-slow) suggests mounting `tmp` as `tmpfs`, which on docker would be done via `sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp`.

How can I do the same in a singularity container?

Answer (score 2):

Since singularity images are (usually) read-only and it is designed to be run by non-root users, the sudo solution is not feasible either in the definition file or as a step run inside the container by the user.

If you want to use a tmpfs mount for tmp, you'll need to create it on the host OS and mount it into the image as you would any other writable directory. `-B /local/tmpfs/dir:/tmp`

**EDIT:** I don't think it's a solution in this case as python is writing to `/tmp` behind the scenes, but you can create a writable tmpfs layer on the image as a whole with `--writable-tmpfs` (see docs: https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/persistent_overlays.html).

Comment: While sort of unrelated , I found a significant increase in speed when I load the nodes os into rsmdisk / tmpfs. The pxe option is toram . If you did this your tmp directory would already be tmpfs. What's 4 - 8 GB of RAM when a hpc node has 256 or greater . :)